# How can I run a terminal command (bash) from C#/Mono?

Tags: camera, mono

I've got an asp.net mvc website up and running great on the pi, and I'm even blinking an led - however, I would like to take a picture from the site using the raspberry pi camera board.  I am attempting to use the following code:

```
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "raspistill -o image.jpg";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
```

However, every time I try to do that I get the error

```
user/bin/raspistill: /usr/bin/raspistill: cannot execute binary file
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working, or how I can run a bash command from mono/C#?

Comment: have you tried to run the same command from the terminal? what was the result?

Comment: How are you running asp.net and mono on your Pi?  I tried installing mono and xsp2 and xsp4 but couldn't get a simple web page to run.

Comment: @lenik - when done from the terminal it works exactly as intended.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn - I followed this tutorial exactly and it worked quite well http://www.codewithmac.com/2013/05/asp-net-mvc-on-your-raspberry-pi/ - the key is installing Debian, not Raspian

Comment: Ah, I'm not running soft-float

Comment: Can you post outputs of 'ldd /path/to/your/prog' and 'file /path/to/your/prog' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

You need to add the `-c` option to the argument string for `/bin/bash`:

```
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c raspistill -o image.jpg";
```

I get the same `cannot execute binary file` when I try to run `/bin/bash /usr/bin/raspistill -?` from the command line.

```
    raspberrypi ~ $ /bin/bash /usr/bin/raspistill -?
    /usr/bin/raspistill: /usr/bin/raspistill: cannot execute binary file
```

Running `/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/raspistill -?` works from the command line.

Also, according to [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699109/mono-process-start-how-to-find-bash) try running `/usr/bin/raspistill` directly from `Process.Start()` as shown below:

```
    Process.Start("/usr/bin/raspistill", "-?");
```

Comment: That's the one!  It works perfectly